# How do I render a url from my database as an iframe src without django rendering the parent page in the iframe?

Tags: python, django

currently, django rerenders the entire page inside the iframe.

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<body>
<section>
    ...
</section>
<iframe src="{% for item in query_set %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;margin-top:-10px;"></iframe>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does `query_set` contain? What is `{{ item }}`? What is the actual and expected html when Django renders the template (in particular for the src value of the iframe tag)?

Comment: it is a query set with one url.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. I suspect the output of item isn't what you think it is.